# How to insert delay into onkeyup event

Tags: delay, onkeyup

How would insert the delay into this snippet of code so that it won't fire till after the user is done typing?

**JS**

```
gridContainer = $('#shuffleContainer');
var sizer = gridContainer.find('.col-md-4');

$('.js-shuffle-search').on('keyup change', function () {
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function ($el, shuffle) {

        // Only search elements in the current group
        if (shuffle.group !== 'all' && $.inArray(shuffle.group, $el.data('groups')) === -1) {
            return false;
        }

        var text = $.trim($el.find('.picture-item__title').text()).toLowerCase();
        return text.indexOf(val) !== -1;
    });
});
```

**JS DELAY**

```
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

$('input').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
        alert('Time elapsed!');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: This question, if I understand it correctly, has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381751/onkeyup-javascript-time-delay?rq=1